# How to catch FTP errors? e.g., socket.error: [Errno 10060]

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm using the ftplib module to upload files:

```
    files = [ a.txt , b.txt , c.txt ]

    s = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server , ftp_user , ftp_pw) # Connect to FTP
    for i in range(len(files)):
            f = open(files[i], 'rb')
            stor = 'stor ' + files[i]
            s.storbinary(stor, f)
            f.close() # close file
    s.quit() # close ftp
```

How do I catch the following error?

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

And what other errors are common when using the FTP module that I should also catch?

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 3):

```
import socket

try:
    s = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server , ftp_user , ftp_pw) # Connect to FTP
except socket.error, e:
    print "do something with %s" % e
```

this will catch all socket errors (whatever their "errno" -- ones 10000 and up are quite Windows specific, they're very different on Unix).

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html?highlight=ftplib#ftplib.FTP) for other exceptions that may be raised; they're all in the tuple `ftplib.all_errors` (as is `socket.error` and the last biggie, `IOError`) so you can handily catch them all with `except ftplib.all_errors, e:`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error.  What I had to do instead is catch the socket.error at the line

```
s.storbinary(stor, f)
```

as well as the initial connection.